# Reading a text file in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, file

I have a text file which has the contents as follows.. I need to read this file column wise (ies, 2 columns here). I have tried many ways.. but cannot do as it contains "(" , "," , ")" etc... please guide..

```
(-2.714141687294326, 0.17700122506478025)
(-2.8889905690592976, 0.1449494260855578)
(-2.74534285564141, 0.3182989792519164)
(-2.728716536554531, -0.3267545129349194)
(-2.280859632844493, -0.7413304490629143)
(-2.8205377507406095, 0.08946138452856946)
(-2.6261449731466335, -0.16338495969832847)
(-2.8863827317805537, 0.5783117541867042)
(-2.6727557978209546, 0.11377424587411682)
(-2.5069470906518565, -0.6450688986485736)
(-2.6127552309087236, -0.01472993916137419)
(-2.7861092661880185, 0.23511200020171835)
(-3.2238037438656533, 0.5113945870063824)
(-2.6447503899420304, -1.1787646364375748)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
x = importdata('filename.txt');
x = regexp(x,'-?\d+\.?\d*','match'); %// detect numbers as [-]a[.][bcd]
x = cellfun(@str2num, vertcat(x{:}));
```

If the file can contain numbers in decimal form ("1.234") and in scientific notation ("1.234e-56"):

```
x = importdata('filename.txt');
x = regexp(x,'-?\d+\.?\d*(e-?\d+)?','match');
x = cellfun(@str2num, vertcat(x{:}));
```

Comment: thankuu very much..this is exactly what I wanted...!!

Comment: what should I do if the **same dataset contains values** like (1.9653316517612152e-13, -0.0013776924983497187)
(1.9690146865411484e-13, -0.0013451512592268559)                                  can u plz suggest any ideas?Also I would like to know what actually happens using the statement ** x = regexp(x,'-?\d+\.?\d*','match'); %// detect numbers as [-]a[.][bcd] ** ..

Comment: See edited answer. As to how it works, read up on regular expressions: http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html, http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: thnk you once again :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`fscanf`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fscanf.html) and specify the desired format:

```
fid = fopen('filename.txt');
x = fscanf(fid,'(%f, %f)\n',[2,inf]).';
fclose(fid);
```

The format spec `'(%f, %f)\n'` reads to float values inside brackets, separated by `,` per line. With `[2,inf]` you specify to put it into a `2 x n` array, where `n` is as large as needed. To have the same format as before, you'll have to transpose it again `.'`.